# Hyperref: Changing the linkcolor locally in the TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, color

I found that the link-color for TOC text is identical to the link-color for Figures and Tables. When I change the color to black in the TOC also the color for Figures/Tables citation etc. is changed.

Is there a way to separately set the colors inside the TOC and outside?

Comment: Is there any chance you can reduce the length of the question?

Comment: @MarcvanDongen: Length of the title of the question: reduced, question itself: well, reworded but not shortened, but I think it is short enough, isn't it?

Comment: @Stephen Much better now.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

`\hypersetup{linkbordercolor=black}` before `\tableofcontents` changes the link colour to black (also for links to Figures and Tables occurring in the TOC). Enclosing `\hypersetup` and `\tableofcontents` in a group (either by enclosing in curly braces `{...}`or by using `\begingroup\hypersetup...\tableofcontents\endgroup`) keeps the change local. (Using "plain colour names" like `black` requires the `xcolor`package.)

If the `colorlinks=true` option of the `hyperref` package is used, `\hypersetup{linkcolor=black}` must be used instead of `\hypersetup{linkbordercolor=black}`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
{\hypersetup{linkbordercolor=black}
% or \hypersetup{linkcolor=black}, if the colorlinks=true option of hyperref is used
\tableofcontents
}
% \hypersetup{linkbordercolor=red} 
% is not necessary because the colour is only changed in the group
\section{First Section starting at page \pageref{s1}\label{s1}}

\ref{s1}

\end{document}
```

[image: compiled MWE]

Because you are using "black" (and assuming your text is written in black) also

```
{\hypersetup{hidelinks}
\tableofcontents
}
```

would be possible, which would - well, hide the links in the TOC.

Comment: +1 you might be able to make it a local change by using `\begingroup\hypersetup....\tableofcontents\endgroup`

Comment: @cmhughes: Yes, I was answering while developing the answer (me bad), had it grouped now by `{}`, but I'll include the alternative in the answer.

Comment: {\hypersetup{linkcolor=black}
\tableofcontents } works perfectly. thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can also choose colors for your hyper references.
Include this in your preamble and modify it according to your needs!

```
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{Darkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.4,0}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{%
    pdfborder = {0 0 0},
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=red,
    filecolor=Darkgreen,
    linkcolor=blue,
    urlcolor=cyan!50!black!90
}
```

Comment: he doesnt just need to modify the link color, but he needs to do it locally, i.e. only for the TOC and not for all the document

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: May not answer the question, but was useful for me.