# How to color the ToC and the references with a different color?

Tags: table-of-contents, cross-referencing, color

As the title reads, I'd like to color my **ToC** in let's say red and the **references** in my document with another color let's say blue.

here's a MWE of my document :

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{test colors}
\author{Oddant}

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linktoc=all,
    linkcolor=blue
}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents


\chapter{foo}
\section{bar}
go to \ref{lipsum}
\chapter{oof}
\section{rab}
\label{lipsum}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

If you compile the code above you would notice that the *ToC* is in the same color than the *reference* in the **bar** section.

> How can I color my *ToC* in black for instance without installing any
>   extra packages like *tocloft* ?

Is there any parameters to place in **hypersetup** to get what I want, i peeked into the documentation of **hyperref** but I come here with any clue.

Comment: Use `\begingroup
\hypersetup{linkcolor=red}
\tableofcontents
\endgroup`

Comment: short and concise, can you make a short answer at least to validate the question ?

Comment: Just noted that this seems to be a duplicate of the question http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88400

Answer (score 3):

The command `\hypersetup` can be used inside the document body. To setup the color you can change the behvaviour inside a local group or by switching.

1. Using a local group:

   ```
   \begingroup
    \hypersetup{linkcolor=red} 
    \tableofcontents 
   \endgroup
   ```
2. Switching:

   ```
    \hypersetup{linkcolor=red} 
    \tableofcontents 
    \hypersetup{linkcolor=blue}
   ```