# Disable `colorlinks` locally (or just for the ToC)

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, color, memoir

Basically, I want to disable the `colorlinks` option (from the `hyperref` package) for the ToC, but keep it enabled for the rest of a (`memoir`) document.

[This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88400/hyperref-changing-the-linkcolor-locally-in-the-toc) has a workaround based on issuing `\hypersetup{linkcolor=black}` before `\tableofcontents`, but this doesn’t work for my case, since I already colour certain parts of the ToC, and `hyperref`’s colouring overrides this. Example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage[colorlinks=false, hidelinks, linkcolor=cyan]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

\renewcommand{\cftchapterfont}{\color{orange}\sffamily\bfseries} 

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents*

\bigskip

See \cref{chap:hello} for more information.

\chapter{Hello}
\label{chap:hello}

\section{Foo}
\section{Bar}

\section{Baz}

\chapter{Goodbye}

\section{Qux}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that the `chapter 1` hyperlink is not coloured, since `colorlinks=false`. If I change it to `true` and remove `hidelinks`, I get:

[image]

I want a combination of the two, with orange chapter names and black section names in the ToC, and light blue hyperlinks in the rest of the document. Issuing `\hypersetup{colorlinks=false}` before `\tableofcontents` has no effect; it only results in the following warning:

```
Package hyperref Warning: Option `colorlinks' has already been used,
setting the option has no effect on input line 13
```

Is it possible to somehow disable `colorlinks` locally, or to make the ToC colouring commands (`\cftchapterfont`) override its effect? The solution needs to work with the `memoir` package (and ToC commands).

Comment: You could use locally `\hypersetup{hidelinks}`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Brilliant! It never occured to me that `hidelinks` could be used locally when `colorlinks` could not. If you add it as an answer, I’ll accept it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could use locally `\hypersetup{hidelinks}`

Comment: I was surprised this worked because I already had `\hypersetup{hidelinks, colorlinks=true, ...}` in my preamble. The order matters.