# How to discolor *ONE* particular link/citation in hyperref?

Tags: hyperref, color

After reading the [hyperref documentation](ftp://tug.ctan.org/pub/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/manual.pdf), I have set several coloring options to hyperref using:

```
\usepackage[colorlinks, 
            linkcolor={blue!50!black}, 
            citecolor={blue!50!black}, 
            urlcolor={blue!50!black}]{hyperref}
```

All links, references are colored now as expected.

The problem is that I also find some of the colored places are undesirable. I either want to *remove* the color or color it differently.

For example, the title page, where carefully designed rest of the colors get disturbed by few email addresses that I do want to link within.

Note that I want to keep links, but only color/discolor them against the rest of the links. Is there a way to do it?

I guess any solution should work which is capable of force *coloring/discoloring* a particular text element, overriding the formats/colors that are going to be applied on a global scale later on.

Comment: Essentially duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88400/hyperref-changing-the-linkcolor-locally-in-the-toc I believe. A `\hypersetup{hidelinks}` inside the `titlepage` environment will for example hide all the links on the titlepage. (Assuming you're using that environment.) Edit: More specific duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/179506/disable-colorlinks-locally-or-just-for-the-toc?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 11):

From the answers available at [hyperref changing the linkcolor locally in the toc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88400/hyperref-changing-the-linkcolor-locally-in-the-toc) and [disable colorlinks locally or just for the toc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/179506/disable-colorlinks-locally-or-just-for-the-toc?noredirect=1&lq=1), here is the more specific answer by myself the OP.

Hopefully it is more comprehensible and reachable than the ones above. (especially for the questions being *ToC*-specific, which could have been the reason why I didn't find in the first place)

---

The main take-away is that `\hypersetup{}`, which is for setting any option of the package `hyperref` outside `\usepackage[..]{hyperref}` call, works not only globally within the header, but also *locally* within the main body of text. So surrounded with braces, it applies those options to any block of text.

Accordingly the specific solution to *coloring problem* is to use something as below.

**For discoloring:**

```
{\hypersetup{hidelinks}<TEXT-OF-INTEREST>}
```

**For coloring differently:**

```
{\hypersetup{allcolors=<COLOR-OF-UR-WISH>}<TEXT-OF-INTEREST>}
```

Some examples with emails, URL-with-anchor, URLs, citations, references, an entire Table-of-contents, or an entire section respectively:

```
<TEXT-OF-INTEREST>  =  \href{mailto:xxxx@xyz.com}{xxxx@xyz.com} 
<TEXT-OF-INTEREST>  =  \href{www.URL.com}{anchor-text} 
<TEXT-OF-INTEREST>  =  \url{www.URL.com} 
<TEXT-OF-INTEREST>  =  \cite{XYZ}
<TEXT-OF-INTEREST>  =  \ref{XYZ}
<TEXT-OF-INTEREST>  =  \tableofcontents
<TEXT-OF-INTEREST>  =  \section{....} ....... block of text .....
```

Thanks to @Torbjørn T.

---

If needed often, or not, you may prefer to use it as a **user-command**.

**For discoloring:**

```
\newcommand{\discolorlinks}[1]{{\hypersetup{hidelinks}#1}}
```

Usage: `\discolorlinks{<TEXT-OF-INTEREST>}`

**For coloring differently:**

The most general one (as a copy of `\textcolor` syntax) in the context of forcing a specific color on *all* links/urls/citations within a block of text (may customize more as you need with options such as `citecolor`, `urlcolor`,`linkcolor`):

```
\newcommand{\colorlinks}[2]{{\hypersetup{allcolors=#1}#2}}
```

Example usage: `\colorlinks{red}{<TEXT-OF-INTEREST>}`