# Fancy Table of Contents and Hyperref Set Up

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, color

I am using a code in `tikz` for a fancy table of contents and I want to apply certain settings on it using the `hyperref` package and the relevant command `hyperrefsetup`. I want to create the following image

[image]

or at least something that will be smooth, like section numbers should have the same color with their title and their page numbering while the chapter title should have this light blue color.

When I use `linkcolor` option(which I actually need it for colored links) there seems to be a mess up, where all of the ToC entries have the same color and not the same color with section/chapter/page numbering, like the following

[image]

or

[image]

How can I achieve the first image and how can I explicitly change section/page numbering color?

My code is the following

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tikz}

%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Fancy ToC~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\definecolor{doc}{RGB}{0,60,110}
\definecolor{myblueii}{RGB}{63,200,244}

\contentsmargin{0cm}
\titlecontents{chapter}[0pc]
{\addvspace{30pt}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]%
\draw[fill=myblueii,draw=myblueii, rounded corners] (-4,-.1) rectangle (-0.15,.5);%
\pgftext[left,x=-2.7cm,y=0.2cm]{\color{white}\Large \chaptertitlename\ \thecontentslabel};%
\end{tikzpicture}\color{myblueii}\large\bfseries}%
{}
{}
{\hspace*{6pt}\titlerule\hspace*{6pt}\large\bfseries \thecontentspage
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\draw[fill=doc!25,draw=myblueii, rounded corners=0pt] (2pt,0) rectangle (6,0.1pt);
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\titlecontents{section}[2.4pc]
{\addvspace{1pt}}
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{2.4pc}}
{}
{\hfill\small \thecontentspage}
[]
\titlecontents{subsection}[4.8pc]
{\addvspace{1.0pt}}
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{2.4pc}}
{}
{\hfill\small\thecontentspage}
[]

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{%
\chapter*{%
\vspace*{-20\p@}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]%
\pgftext[right,x=15cm,y=0.2cm]{\color{myblueii}\Huge \contentsname};%
\draw[fill=myblueii,draw=myblueii, rounded corners=15pt] (13,-.75) rectangle (20,1);%
\clip (13,-.75) rectangle (20,1);
\pgftext[right,x=15cm,y=0.2cm]{\color{white}\Huge \contentsname};%
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\@starttoc{toc}}
\makeatother

%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Hyperref Settings~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{%
    pdfborder = {0 0 0},
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=red,
    filecolor=green,
    linkcolor=myblueii,
    urlcolor=cyan!50!black!90
}

%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Main Document~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents
  \chapter{rkbnjg}
  \section{ljkihb;kjb}
  \url{http://www.google.com}
  \section{lkhb;hkb}
  \section{;kjbkjb}
  \subsection{;kjblkhjblhkb}
  \subsection{lhjbljh}
  \subsection{;jbnlkhjblbh}
  \section{ljhblkhbj}
  \subsection{ljhblhjkblkbh}
  \chapter{kgjb}
  \chapter{;kjdfb543}
\end{document}
```

Comment: do you need links in your document to be coloured? since if i comment out all of `colorlinks, citecolor=red, filecolor=green, linkcolor=myblueii` from your MWE I get exactly the result you show in your first picture.

Comment: @greyshade : Thank you very much for your comment! I know that when you comment `colorlinks` I get the behaviour that I want, but in fact I do need to have colored link in my document

Comment: you might state that in your question somewhere;)

Comment: @greyshade : I will, right now! Sorry for the inconvenience!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, with all the link colouring commented out, you get the correct result. Thus, locally use the `hidelinks` option when the `\tableofcontents` is evoked (inspired by [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88400/hyperref-changing-the-linkcolor-locally-in-the-toc)). I.e. write:

```
{
  \hypersetup{hidelinks}
  \tableofcontents%
}
```

The complete code then should be:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%
\definecolor{doc}{RGB}{0,60,110}
\definecolor{myblueii}{RGB}{63,200,244}

%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Hyperref Settings~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\hypersetup{%
    pdfborder = {0 0 0},
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=red,
    filecolor=green,
    linkcolor=myblueii,
    urlcolor=cyan!50!black!90
}

%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Fancy ToC~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\contentsmargin{0cm}
\titlecontents{chapter}[0pc]
{\addvspace{30pt}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]%
\draw[fill=myblueii,draw=myblueii, rounded corners] (-4,-.1) rectangle (-0.15,.5);%
\pgftext[left,x=-2.7cm,y=0.2cm]{\color{white}\Large \chaptertitlename\ \thecontentslabel};%
\end{tikzpicture}\color{myblueii}\large\bfseries}%
{}
{}
{\hspace*{6pt}\titlerule\hspace*{6pt}\large\bfseries \thecontentspage
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\draw[fill=doc!25,draw=myblueii, rounded corners=0pt] (2pt,0) rectangle (6,0.1pt);
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\titlecontents{section}[2.4pc]
{\addvspace{1pt}}
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{2.4pc}}
{}
{\hfill\small \thecontentspage}
[]
\titlecontents{subsection}[4.8pc]
{\addvspace{1.0pt}}
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{2.4pc}}
{}
{\hfill\small\thecontentspage}
[]

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{%
\chapter*{%
\vspace*{-20\p@}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]%
\pgftext[right,x=15cm,y=0.2cm]{\color{myblueii}\Huge \contentsname};%
\draw[fill=myblueii,draw=myblueii, rounded corners=15pt] (13,-.75) rectangle (20,1);%
\clip (13,-.75) rectangle (20,1);
\pgftext[right,x=15cm,y=0.2cm]{\color{white}\Huge \contentsname};%
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\@starttoc{toc}}
\makeatother

%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Main Document~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\begin{document}
{
  \hypersetup{hidelinks}
  \tableofcontents%
}
  \chapter{rkbnjg}
  \section{ljkihb;kjb}
  \url{http://www.google.com}
  \section{lkhb;hkb}
  \section{;kjbkjb}
  \subsection{;kjblkhjblhkb}
  \subsection{lhjbljh}
  \subsection{;jbnlkhjblbh}
  \section{ljhblkhbj}
  \subsection{ljhblhjkblkbh}
  \chapter{kgjb}
  \chapter{;kjdfb543}
\end{document}
```

which outputs:

[image: output]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Although, it works for me, I think it would be very educational to do the coloring, separately for (sub)section numbers, titles and pages.