# Temporarily prevent hyperref from decorating links

Tags: hyperref, links

I have a picture, drawn with tikz, that contains a few slanted hyperrefs (in fact, document-internal references). For these, the colored underline that I have told hyperref to draw are not slanted, so they greatly impair the prettiness of the drawing.

Is there a way to modify hyperref’s options, in particular `hidelinks` and/or `colorlinks` only temporary?

Comment: Have a look at <http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88400/hyperref-changing-the-linkcolor-locally-in-the-toc>

Comment: Thanks; although the question is phrased more specific, it’s answer does answer my more general question perfectly. I guess this can be closed as a duplicate.