# Table of contents and colors

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, color

I wanted to know if it is possible to have the table of contents in black like it appears in the picture:
[image]

And also make the sections appears in blue when referencing them:

[image]

This is my current set up:

```
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=black,
    filecolor=blue,      
    urlcolor=blue,
    citecolor=blue,
    %pdfpagemode=FullScreen,
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want hyperlinks in the table of contents boxed, but the hyperlinks for cross references coloured?

Comment: Not boxed, only black. And the hyperlinks for cross references blue coloured!

Comment: So just different styles. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88400/hyperref-changing-the-linkcolor-locally-in-the-toc

Comment: Basically you want: `{\hypersetup{linkcolor=black}\tableofcontents}`

Comment: Let my try it and I'll tell you. I want to keep the blue hyperlinks for cross references colored

Comment: This is how I have it right now. Check the edited post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this will do what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    allcolors=blue
}

\begin{document}

{\hypersetup{hidelinks}
\tableofcontents
}

\section{Section heading}
\label{sec}

Filler text.

\section{Another section heading}
\label{anothersec}

Filler text. §\ref{sec}. Filler text. §\ref{anothersec}.

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Wow!!! You did it! Such a wonderful job! It works but, I have the preamble, meaning, all the packages, separated from the main.tex file. I can only alter the document from the preamble. By putting `{\hypersetup{hidelinks}
\tableofcontents` below `\begin{document}` the table of contents appears in the first page and then comes the title page. How can we fix that?
}

Comment: @Delan, you must have an existing `\tableofcontents` somewhere in your document. Just replace that line with `{\hypersetup{hidelinks}\tableofcontents}`

Comment: I want to alter the whole document, yes! I am trying to find where `\tableofcontents` is. I am seeing that I have it like `\input{tableofcontents}`

Comment: Or you could use `{\hypersetup{hidelinks}\input{tableofcontents}}`

Comment: It worked!!!! I did the following: `{\hypersetup{hidelinks}
  \input{tableofcontents}
}`

Comment: I need list of figures and list of tables also in black. How can we alter that? Right now the table of contents is appearing in black and everything else, in blue. Which is fantastic. But I need to make both lists, figures and tables in black also, because it does not match the style then. But so far, you're a genius

Comment: @Delan. Same way. Just surround you list of figure and list of tables with `{\hypersetup{hidelinks}…}`.

Comment: Done! It looks fantastic! Thank you very much!