# Mini table of content in black color and cite in blue

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, color, hyperlink

I was wondering how can I set the mini table of contents in black and the rest in blue?

[image]

This is what I've got right now:

```
{\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=blue,      
    urlcolor=blue,
    citecolor=blue,
    pdfpagemode=FullScreen,
}
```

Comment: As usual here on this site, please add a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) to your question. How do you produce your "mini table of contents"? With the help of the `minitoc` package? Is there another overall table of contents? What exactly should be black (isn't it already black in the screenshot you show?)? The page numbers, the chapter titles,...? What is "the rest"  that should be blue? Please add some clarifications along with your MWE.

Comment: I want the table of contents bot mini and normal, in black. Cite colors in blue and numbers that are used, as an example when you use `Figure \ref{blbla}` , to appear in blue.

Comment: Probably useful: [Hyperref: Changing the linkcolor locally in the TOC](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88400/134144)